# Can't import mx.core.FlexGlobals with Flex SDK 4.6

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

I'm trying to access mx.core.FlexGlobals, but I keep getting the error that it can't be imported. I'm using the Flex 4.6.0 SDK and it should be part of it.

```
import mx.core.FlexGlobals;
```

Gives the error: The import FlexGlobals could not be found.

Using my IDE it also does not show up as an option after mx.core.
[image: CODE COMPLETION PICTURE]

I can't seem to get it done either in Flash Builder 4.6 or Flash Builder 4.7. Am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your project is probably a pure actionscript project.
[image]

It needs to be converted to a Flex Project to use FlexGlobals.

My guess is that you do not want to do that based on the fact that you are using Starling.

Comment: Thanks, indeed. I came to the same conclusion after experimenting a bit more.